# MoveNext() exception after inserting data from WP8 to Azure Database (Mobile services)

Tags: azure, windows-phone-8, azure-mobile-services

I've got question connected with `Windows Azure` / `Windows Phone 8 services`

After I Tap button, use refresh_button_Tap event I've got message with MessageBox:

> "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object. at
>   pic.MainPage.d__0.MoveNext()"

Then I just Tap Ok, and new record appear in `Azure Database`.

```
public class UsersTableItem
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "Login")]
        public string Login { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

    }

    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // MobileServiceCollectionView implements ICollectionView (useful for databinding to lists) and 
        // is integrated with your Mobile Service to make it easy to bind your data to the ListView
        //private MobileServiceCollectionView<PicturesTableItem> items;

        private IMobileServiceTable<PicturesTableItem> picturesTable = App.MobileService.GetTable<PicturesTableItem>();

        private MobileServiceCollectionView<UsersTableItem> items;

        private IMobileServiceTable<UsersTableItem> usersTable = App.MobileService.GetTable<UsersTableItem>();

        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private async void InsertUsersTableItem(UsersTableItem UsersTableItem)
        {
            // This code inserts a new PicturesTableItem into the database. When the operation completes
            // and Mobile Services has assigned an Id, the item is added to the CollectionView
            try
            {

                await usersTable.InsertAsync(UsersTableItem);
                items.Add(UsersTableItem);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            }
        }

        private void refresh_button_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
        {
            var usersTableItem = new UsersTableItem {Login = "LOL", Password = "9E32581C5C0D680FFC7D95C370D3260B" };
            InsertUsersTableItem(usersTableItem);
        }
    }
```

**Azure SQL**

```
USE [pic_db]
GO

/**** Object:  Table [pic].[UsersTableItem]    Script Date: 2013-02-19 22:02:47 ****/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [pic].[UsersTableItem](
       [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
       [Login] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
       [Password] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_UsersTableItem] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
       [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)

GO
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Do you have `Microsoft.CompilerServices.AsyncTargetingPack` installed?

Comment: I use VS 2012, but got message from NUGET

Microsoft.CompilerServices.AsyncTargetingPack could not be installed because it is not comatible with any project in the solution.

Check .NETFramework, Version=v4.0
Check .NETFramework, Version=v4.5
Silverlight, Version=v5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code, I don't see you initializing the `items` collection, so `items.Add(UsersTableItem);` would appear to be the culprit, and it happens after the `InsertAsync`, so your data does indeed arrive in the database just fine.

Comment: Yes, that's one part of the problem.

My code is from Azure TodoItem sample. I delete a part

private void RefreshTodoItems(){ items = UsersTableItem.ToCollectionView(); }

Answer (score 0):

First of all, thank you Jim O'Neil.

But there is something more. It's Network Connection Issue from Hyper-V and my Wifi. My Hyper-V emulator connect to the internet with 1 minute delay. Firstly app just run and after a while synchronize clock. But there still no connection. After one minute connection is really avaible.

due to: [related topic](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/it-it/azuremobile/thread/751e414b-c00d-4818-97a3-dc6b0081c43a)

Today I download again sample TodoItems project from my Azure. And they use something like that to initialize **items** collection.

```
private void RefreshTodoItems()
        {
            // This code refreshes the entries in the list view be querying the TodoItems table.
            // REMOVED the filter on completed items, so they're all dislpayed
            items = todoTable
                //.Where(todoItem => todoItem.Complete == false)
                .ToCollectionView();
            ListItems.ItemsSource = items;
        }

protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            RefreshTodoItems();
        }
```

RefreshTodoItems won't work correctly if emulator can't reach connection. So my problem appears also with test sample project from Azure. I am not only one who got Wifi / Hyper-V emulator problem. I should buy Windows Phone 8 device or Microsoft should fix that issue.